# How to submit a form on SUBMIT or ENTER button

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am trying to follow a [tutorial](http://www.w3resource.com/ajax/working-with-PHP-and-MySQL.php) and [demo](http://www.w3resource.com/ajax/ajax-php-mysql-user-interface.html). But when I press SUBMIT or ENTER button, it is not submitting, it is just refreshing the page :( and showing an error.

It shows an alert

> There was a problem with the request.

And the page refreshes.

**My form**

```
<form class="well-home span6 form-horizontal" name="ajax-demo" id="ajax-demo"> <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="book">Book</label>
              <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="book" onKeyUp="book_suggestion()">
                <div id="suggestion"></div>
             </div>  </div>  <div class="control-group">
              <div class="controls">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
              </div>  
       </div> 
</form>
```

**And my Javascript**

```
<script>
function book_suggestion()
{
var book = document.getElementById("book").value;
var xhr;
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE 8 and older
    xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
var data = "book_name=" + book;
     xhr.open("POST", "book-suggestion.php", true); 
     xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");                  
     xhr.send(data);
     xhr.onreadystatechange = display_data;
    function display_data() {
     if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
      if (xhr.status == 200) {
       //alert(xhr.responseText);      
      document.getElementById("suggestion").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
      } else {
        alert('There was a problem with the request.');
      }
     }
    }
}
</script>
```

**book-suggestion.php**

```
<?php  
include('../includes/dbopen.php');  
$book_name = $_POST['book_name'];  
$sql = "select book_name from book_mast where book_name LIKE '$book_name%'";  
$result = mysql_query($sql);  
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))  
{  
echo "<p>".$row['book_name']."</p>";  
}  
?>
```

Comment: oh, dear Amazon, please, let kindle help us!

Comment: on a more serious note, we need to see your code to check how to remove the error

Comment: @svetlio thanks a ton. :) i just did as it is in that tutorial... but got this error..

Comment: @STTLCU have updated my question with the code...

Comment: first study the basic theory THEN learn through tutorials. You can't skip basic theory. Anyway, I removed the downvote

Comment: (It's spelled *kindly* :) )

Comment: @VidavalapatiAkhilesh You may think using jQuery and in your case jQuery.ajax . Its a lot easier for use if you are not familiar with pure Javascript..

Comment: Try to request the book-suggestion.php script yourself (from the browser) and see what kind of error you get. I expect you get an error 404 or 500.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/1190388) in new code. They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the red box? Learn about prepared statements instead, and use [tag:PDO] or [tag:MySQLi].

Comment: @Veda yes i have tied :) it is not showing me any error, but it is showing my complete DB there :O

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: @KateGregory I didn't edit any code formatting here

Comment: @KateGregory no, I can edit what I can edit at the moment, if you notice other errors you're free to give your contribution too.

Comment: @KateGregory I'll leave it alone.

Answer (score 0):

The submit button used there is not participating in the demo. The purpose of the demo is to show how to fetch data with ajax **when user types data in the text box**. It may, for sure be extended so that the submit button acts upon and adds some more functions, but for now, that has not been added to the demo.